# Why is linear charge density used for field of conducting cylinder?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge

here is a page from hyperphysics explaining conducting cylinder electric field. Why do they use linear charge density

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Physics SE. It could prove to be beneficial to provide some more information into what you cannot understand, what have you tried yourself to answer your question and if so, where did you get stuck. This way, people will be able to provide help easier.

Comment: In addition to the comment above, please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead. When you quote another page on the internet, please provide a link to the source.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is it that when calculating the electric field of a cylinder, the linear charge density is used?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/572385/why-is-it-that-when-calculating-the-electric-field-of-a-cylinder-the-linear-cha)

Answer (score 0):

Notice that in both cases they specify an infinite cylinder.  In the case of a conductor, this is necessary, otherwise the charge (which must stay on the surface) would spread until the field was zero at each point inside (and just inside the surface). For a uniform volume charge density, the cylinder must be a non-conductor. Since Gauss's lay is only simple when you have high symmetry, the length should be long.  (To actually produce a volume charge density, you would need a 3D printer which sprays a charged non-conductor.)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the place you are stuck at is why are we using linear charge density when the charge on a conducting cylinder is spread on the surface area of that cylinder.

So while applying Gauss Law, we need the charge present on some length 'l' of the cylinder which can be easily written considering linear charge density.

However you can just as easily write it in terms of surface charge density using:

$\sigma = \frac {\lambda}{2{\pi}R}$

where

$\sigma$ = Surface charge density

$\lambda$ = Linear charge density

R = Radius of cylinder